# PL/SQL Oracle Sql - Filter query results by max of column/attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

i haven't really touched much of PL/SQL before this project and my current knowledge of DBs is limited to SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL and other non sql DB technologies so bear with me on this.

First i started with a query that would get me the max difference in hours between two dates for each ID i had on that table. It goes something like this:

```
SELECT 
   id_trip as ID, 
   MAX(24 * (Trip.actual_arrival_date- (Trip.programmed_arrival_date))) as MAX_DELAY_HOURS
   FROM Trip
   GROUP BY ID
```

And that returns me something like this:

[Results of first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx4gS.png)

So i can say that i successfully went into the all the trips that exist for each ID and got the ones that have the maximum delay.

Now what i want to do after that is to join other types of information to that table, namely the actual date of the trip, the name of the departure spot and the name of the arrival spot. So i did something like this:

```
SELECT 
      internal_ID as external_ID,
      programmed_date,
      starting_airport.name as starting_airport,
      destination_airport.name as destination_airport,
      24 * (Trip.actual_arrival_date- (Trip.programmed_arrival_date)) AS external_delay
      FROM Regular_flight
      INNER JOIN Trip ON Regular_flight.ID = Trip.ID_Regular_flight
      INNER JOIN Flight ON Regular_flight.ID_Flight = Flight.ID
      INNER JOIN Airport starting_airport ON starting_airport.ID_IATA = Flight.ID_STARTING_AIRPORT
      INNER JOIN Airport destination_airport ON destination_airport.ID_IATA = Voo.ID_DESTINATION_AIRPORT
      INNER JOIN ( 
            --this is the query that i built before--
            SELECT 
                 id_trip as internal_ID, 
                 MAX(24 * (Trip.actual_arrival_date- (Trip.programmed_arrival_date))) as MAX_DELAY_HOURS
            FROM Trip
            GROUP BY ID
       ) ON internal_ID = external_ID
       Order by external_ID;
```

And this actually returns something like this:

[Results of second query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41yj3.png)

Now my problem is that while i have all the info i need there... i wanted to filter it out so that it only shows me the highest EXTERNAL_DELAY for each EXTERNAL_ID.

Usually i'd do a GROUP BY EXTERNAL_ID but since i'm selecting many things not just EXTERNAL_ID it won't actually execute the code. I've tried to do a GROUP BY with all the columns i'm selecting in the external query but then i have all the "combinations" between the external_ID and Programmed_date which is not what i'm looking for.

Basically from the 2nd query i want to reach something like this:

```
   | EXTERNAL_ID | PROGRAMMED_DATE | STARTING_AIRPORT                | DESTINATION_AIRPORT             | EXTERNAL_DELAY |
   |     1       |     16.07.08    | Aeroporto de Gatwick            | Aeroporto Francisco Sa Carneiro |       744      |
   |     2       |     16.08.08    | Aeroporto de Gatwick            | Aeroporto Francisco Sa Carneiro |       0        |
   |     3       |     16.08.09    | Aeroporto Francisco Sa Carneiro | Aeroporto Francisco Sa Carneiro |       744      |
```

And so on for each ID, so basically for each ID the the MAXIMUM delay found no matter what the date is.

I've been scratching my head for a few hours now and i'd like to have someone point me out in the right direction.

Appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT x.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY external_ID ORDER BY external_delay DESC NULLS LAST) r
    FROM  (
  SELECT internal_ID AS external_ID,
    programmed_date,
    starting_airport.name                                           AS starting_airport,
    destination_airport.name                                        AS destination_airport,
    24 * (Trip.actual_arrival_date- (Trip.programmed_arrival_date)) AS external_delay
  FROM Regular_flight
  INNER JOIN Trip
  ON Regular_flight.ID = Trip.ID_Regular_flight
  INNER JOIN Flight
  ON Regular_flight.ID_Flight = Flight.ID
  INNER JOIN Airport starting_airport
  ON starting_airport.ID_IATA = Flight.ID_STARTING_AIRPORT
  INNER JOIN Airport destination_airport
  ON destination_airport.ID_IATA = Voo.ID_DESTINATION_AIRPORT
  INNER JOIN
    (
    --this is the query that i built before--
    SELECT id_trip                                                         AS internal_ID,
      MAX(24 * (Trip.actual_arrival_date- (Trip.programmed_arrival_date))) AS MAX_DELAY_HOURS
    FROM Trip
    GROUP BY ID
    )
  ON internal_ID = external_ID
  ) x) WHERE r   =1 
  Order by external_ID;
```

Comment: It seems to work exactly for what i wanted, it adds a row R but that's not really an issue for me, mind trying to walk me through the steps behind your thought process so i can better understand what i was missing and how to go about it next time i come across it? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: This is typical solution in such situation. Read about analytic functions (ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK() etc).

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() basically numbers rows in the group (as defined by PARTITION BY)  by 1 to N, sorting by given field (external_delay in your case). Then you are selecting only first row in every group (by WHERE r=1 at the end). That is it.

Comment: Hmm it seems that it's not very correct though.. so like i know there's a few instances of trips where the delay was higher than 0 or null particularly for the trip with id's 7 and 9 and yet on this query you gave me it's returning null for some reason? Any guesses? Thanks for the tips i will look further into Analytic functions

Comment: add NULLS LAST to order by. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! Also added a Where delays > 0 so i dont get the 0's and it was perfect! Thanks for the help!